# how come triangle inequality does not hold in this example?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $C([0,1])$ be the set of continuous real-valued functions on $[0,1]$
Define $\langle f,g\rangle =\int_0^1 fg$, then $\langle,\rangle$ is an inner product on $C([0,1])$
Define $\|f\|=\sqrt{\langle f,f \rangle}$.

Let $f(t)=t$ and $g(t)=\operatorname{e}^t$

Then, by triangle inequality, $\|f+g\| \le \|f\| + \|g\|$

However, if i evaluate integrals, i get $\|f+g\|>\|f\| + \|g\|$

How come?

Comment: What did you evaluate the integrals to?

Comment: $||f+g||^2=\int_0^1 (t+e^t)^2 = \int_0^1 t^2 + 2<t,e^t> + \int_0^1 e^{2t} = ||f||^2 + 2<t,e^t> + ||g||^2$..

Comment: Since $<t,e^t> >0, ||f+g||>||f|| + ||g||$

Comment: It looks like you believe that $x^2>y^2+z^2$ implies $x>y+z$ (and that is most likely because you think the square root is additive). Take $x=\sqrt{3}$, $y=z=1$.

Comment: Actually, this tells you that $||f+g||^2 > ||f||^2+||g||^2$ (which is true) but this does not imply that $||f+g|| > ||f||+||g||$. Check out the wikipedia pages for "Cauchy-Schwarz inequality" for information about how the triangle inequality can be proved in general, and "Freshman's dream" if you don't see why the implication isn't valid.

Answer (score 3):

Since $\lVert f\rVert\ge0$ for all $f$, then to show $$\lVert f+g\rVert\le\lVert f\rVert+\lVert g\rVert,$$ we may equivalently show that $$\lVert f+g\rVert^2\le\bigl(\lVert f\rVert+\lVert g\rVert\bigr)^2,$$ that is, $$\lVert f+g\rVert^2\le\lVert f\rVert^2+2\lVert f\rVert\cdot\lVert g\rVert+\lVert g\rVert^2.\tag{1}$$ This is **not** the same as showing $$\lVert f+g\rVert^2\le\lVert f\rVert^2+\lVert g\rVert^2.\tag{2}$$ Though $(2)$ will imply $(1)$, there may be times (such as in your example) when $(1)$ holds and $(2)$ does not.